# Azure worker role getting stuck in Role state Unknown

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Azure toolkit 1.5

1. Create New project
2. Add worker role
3. Hit F5

The deployments get stuck in:

[fabric] Role Instance: deployment(189).WindowsAzureProject1.WorkerRole1.0

[fabric] Role state Unknown

Eventually the deployment times out.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: I have the same problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/3e36d43c-cdfe-4603-9001-ffa8f5003ed4/
Where did you find error log of Azure SDK Tooling?

Comment: Just have submitted a ticket to Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/netservices/feedback/details/689450/local-deployment-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-azure-sdk-1-5-tools-sep-2011#details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working, turned out that Windows Process Activation Service wasn't running correctly on my machine. Reinstalled and enabled tcp activation and now its working!

Comment: I have exactly the same error. Can you please elaborate on how to "re-install and enable TCP activation"?

Comment: I just readded the application server role (win 2008 r2). I have a hunch that this also could be related to me having the OnlyUseLatestCLR set to 1 (http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/276150-getting-powershell-use-net-4-0-runtime.html)

Comment: I tried setting OnlyUseLatestCLR registry value, but that didn't help. Also I am on Win7, there are no application server role.. I tried re-installing "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 / .. Activation" in windows features. It didn't help either. Maybe you did something else before it started working for you?

Comment: Is the "Windows Process Activation Service" running on your box?

Comment: Also check the logs that gets created when you deploy to devfabric

Comment: Yep, "Windows Process Activation Service" is running. There are no any errors in windows application event log. Here I posted exceptions which Dev Fabric Controller and Dev Favbric Agent throws: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/3e36d43c-cdfe-4603-9001-ffa8f5003ed4/

Comment: It looks for me that DF Agent cannot register it's endpoint. Here is what it writes in its log: "There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:808. Make sure that you are not trying to use this endpoint multiple times in your application and that there are no other applications listening on this endpoint." .. But there are no any processing listening on port 808 on my PC.

Answer (score 3):

I personally solved this problem by removing *:808 binding in IIS Manager for Default Website.

Answer (score 2):

The required Azure assemblies may be missing from the package you are deploying to Azure.

Double check that each Azure assembly your project is referencing has the copy to local property set to true.

The following article may help to debug the problem:

[Debugging MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966484.aspx)

Comment: Found the logs, seems like its looping on this exception: http://pastie.org/2536289

Comment: Sorry, but I misread your first post. I thought you were attempting to deploy to the cloud.

Comment: The following article is old, but, hopefully, it helps: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/c2d7d56b-99ba-4b05-85a3-00bb32680ef6)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: roles were permanently stuck in Unknown state and never started properly. Turns out that Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service (SMSvcHost.exe) had taken port 808 and this prevented dev fabric from starting the roles. I restarted the service, and now my roles run fine in dev fabric.

So if you run into the same problem, see if port 808 has been taken by some other process.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas,

You're probably missing an assembly reference or have a startup script issue, best way to continue is to try the deployment with intellitrace enabled.

Comment: Is there a way to use intellitrace without VS 2010 Ultimate?  Given that this is a completely fresh project there should be no way that I'm missing references right?

Comment: No, no other way than ultimate... if you have a 32 bit machine it could be that you drag along the 32 bit msshrtmi.dll file to a 64 bit environment.